# How to get value from select in trigger mysql and use it for condition of IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, mariadb

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cek
AFTER INSERT ON lapor_karya
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @var = (SELECT COUNT(lapor_karya.ID_Lapor) FROM lapor_karya GROUP BY NEW.ID_Karya);
IF(@var > 10)
THEN
DELETE * FROM karya_pelajar WHERE ID_Karya=NEW.ID_Karya;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM karya_pelajar WHERE ID_Karya=NEW.ID_Karya;
END IF;
END' at line 9
```

I want to get value from lapor_karya table, and use this value for condition IF. If my value more than 10, then will execute query delete. But it's doesn't working

Comment: The `GROUP BY` feels "wrong".  That is usually used to deliver multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error which you got about the `DELETE` statement. You have to leave `*` when you writing `DELETE` statement.

Also, just try without parentheses.

```
IF @var > 10 THEN
DELETE FROM karya_pelajar WHERE ID_Karya=NEW.ID_Karya;
END IF;
```

For more info, check this out MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Answer (score 0):

A slight simplification:

```
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lapor_karya
            WHERE ??? = NEW.ID_Karya
       ) > 10
    THEN
        DELETE * FROM karya_pelajar WHERE ID_Karya=NEW.ID_Karya;
    END IF;
END $$
```

That is, a parenthesized `SELECT` that returns a single value can be used virtually any place where an expression can be used.